# Application Takes too long to respond

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, devexpress

I'm using devexpress grid view to view and saving data,my problem is when the browser is first loaded application respond normally,after while (less than 5 minute),application response become very low and takes too long time to respond for any action ,i tried to to expand recycle time(regular time interval) on IIS but seems that the problem is not from IIS at all
also i made session time out after 60 minute and likewise there is no difference.
note that:

- All of my request is Ajax calls.
- When i deploy the application using development Server (in visual studio) application   respond normally.

could any one please suggest me where the problem is??

Comment: What an open-ended question! The problem could be anywhere! We would need more information to give you anything useful, but start eliminating variables. Comment out any database calls first to see if that might be the issue. Check the sizes of the requests and responses to see if there's just a huge amount of viewstate and/or HTML going across the wire. Keep eliminating variables until you get more information.

Comment: This would equate to looking for a needle in a massive stack full of needles.. As @BrandonMontgomery said, please post some code or what you have tried so far so we can try and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i investigate my problem further more i guess the problem is from browser, when i deploy application using Firefox issue totally disappeared and app respond normally,when using IE or chrome problem reveal

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say where is the problem , but first thing came in to my head

- It may be possible connection are opened but not closed, In general not disposing objects.
- Make sure that the database connection pool settings are correct.
- You may try to check the IIS logs to see if there is any unusual response rate i.e. errors (http 500, 404, etc)
- also I will suggests fetching multiple result sets in one database call , try to reduce number of round trips to the database
- It may possible that you have installed so many plugins in your browsers, and they are making it slow.

These are just few tips, hope it will help.